Bezout's identity for Rings
We know that if  $F$ be a field and $F[x]$ is a polynomial ring, then $\gcd(p(x),q(x)) = 1\Longrightarrow \exists r(x),s(x)$ such that $r(x)p(x)+s(x)q(x) = 1$.

Can we say this same if $f(x), g(x) \in \Bbb Z/(p^2 \Bbb Z)[x]$?

If $f(x), g(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$, then can we say that $\gcd(f(x),g(x)) = 1 \pmod{p} \iff \gcd(f(x),g(x)) = 1 \pmod{p^{2}}$?

Now, can we apply Bezout's identity so that there exist two polynomials $ a(x), b(x)$ such that $ a(x)f(x) + b(x)g(x) = 1 \pmod{p^{2}}$?

Then we can also say that $a(x), b(x)$ such that $a(x)f(x) + b(x)g(x) = 1 \pmod{p}$
But I don't have any idea how to prove the converse.

Are $f$ and $g$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(p^2\mathbb{Z})[x]$ or $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ for the second part?

I think that in that ring, the division algorithm does not exist, so the gcd concept is not defined. So maybe we can talk only about Bezout's identity. But we can't able to say in terms of GCD.

We are looking in mod $p^2$, so I  we are ultimately in $\Bbb Z/(p^2 \Bbb Z)$

You are right with the fact that
$$ \gcd(f(x),g(x)) = 1 \mod p^2 \implies \gcd(f(x),g(x)) = 1 \mod p $$
Because if we let the gcd equal $d(x)$ we then have:
$$ d(x) = 1 + p^2 a(x)$$
for some function $a(x)$ which then gives us:
$$ d(x) = 1 + p(pa(x)) \implies d(x) =1\mod p$$
However, the converse is not necessarily true. We can think of the simple case where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are constant functions. A simple case of this would be $f(x) = g(x) = 8$ with $p=7$. We then have $\gcd(f(x),g(x)) = 8 \equiv 1\mod 7 \not \equiv 1 \mod 49$.
EDIT:
For a non-constant example we can take any two polynomials with the only common factor being $2x+1$. Then, we have that the gcd is equal to 1 mod 2. However, we still do not have that this is equal to 1 mod 4.

Can we give an example of $f(x) \neq g(x)$? Because this is a trivial example, and if they are equal, then there is no point in computing their greatest common divisor.

@Afritu: just take $f(x) = 24$ and $g(x) = 40$.

If you want a non-constant example you can use $f(x) = 2x+1$ and $g(x) = (2x+1)^2$. This then gives us the gcd is $2x+1$. If we then let $p=2$ we get that the gcd is 1 mod 2 but not 1 mod 4.

Thanks for the answer. I suggest you to update your answer with this.

Also I updated something in my question. Can you answer that. Actually I couldn’t able to frame that question properly. So I updated it later
